# Where can i get source code of IoOutput8 ()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm looking for the code of IoOutput8 () function ,which is used to write a value to the specified I/O port.

Can anybody help knowing the right location of this functions source code??

Comment: Has `grep` not turned anything up?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, there is no `IoOutput8()` function. You should use `void iowrite8(u8 value, void *addr);` followed by the `wmb();` (write memory barrier). For more details, see [§9.4.2 Accessing I/O Memory](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4) of LDD Book (also see §9.4.3. Ports as I/O Memory for `ioport_map/ioport_unmap`).

As for the source code for `IoOutput8()`, you should probably get it from the same place you got that function. The only place I could find it is Phoenix IO Access Library, if that is something you are using, you should ask Phoenix company for the source code if they haven't provided it already.